# IBM RAD 7.5 update "Installation Manager" failed

Tags: installation, ibm-rad

I'm trying to install IBM RAD 7.5.

First step is to install Installation Manager (IM)

- run launch pad from command window started with admin rights

  c:\temp\IBM Rational Application Developer for WebSphere V7.5\RAD_SETUP>launchpa
  d.exe -c demoDisableAutorun launchpad\launchpad.bat
- Installation completed and ask to restart IM
- IM detects new version and ask to update

Update fails with log
[image: IBM_IM_ErrorLog.PNG]

Files IBMIM.exe and IBMIMc.exe already renamed to ".IBMIM_TMP_1" and ".IBMIM_TMP_2" and can't be found.

Any suggestions what I can try to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

We too were facing the issue and found that the **Automatic Update of Installation Manager** at the time of installation is causing the problem.

We just **TURNED OFF** the internet at the time of installation so that no updates happen and installation is directly done from RAD software Disks or Local drives.

Comment: @staticVoidMan: why is this not an answer?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel : hm.. my bad. i didn't critically read the answer.